# Display a confirmation dialog before sending SMS

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-alertdialog, messagebox

I am new to Android and I have bound my application completely but I wish to a change now in it.

When someone sends an sms, I want to display a confirmation dialog for sending sms asking for send or not. And I have to make a common class for that I have written the source code and it works fine but if user does not click on Yes or Cancel the dialog goes out but I wish that it will still display until user does not click on Yes or Cancel button.

How it can be solved?

```
public void send_SMS( final String message)
    { 
    try{


        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        dialog.setTitle("Send SMS");
        dialog.setMessage("Are U sure want to Send SMS");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sentpi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, new Intent(SENT),0);
                delpi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);//
                String id = message.substring(3, 4);
                int msgId = Integer.valueOf(id, 16).intValue();

                if(dba.IsConOpenOrClose()==false)
                    dba.Open();
                if(ConstantClass.SelectCord.equals("All")){
                    if(msgId == 3 || msgId == 9){   
                    devId = message.substring(4, 20);
                    ConstantClass.CurrentId = devId;
                    strSql = new String("SELECT * FROM "+ ConstantClass.dbName[2] + " WHERE " + DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevID + " = ?");
                    cur = dba.ExecuteSelect(strSql, devId);
                    if(cur!=null)
                        cur.moveToFirst();
                    int cordId = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevCoordId));
                    phoneNumber = dba.getSendSmsMobileNo(cordId);
                    dba.prcUpdateOrClean(devId, 1);
                    cur.close();
                    }
                }else{
                    phoneNumber = dba.getSendSmsMobileNo(dba.CurrentWorkingCoordinator(DataBaseAdapter.Key_SendCoord, 1));
                /*********now getting the Field smsProcess Update for particular devices ********************/
                if(msgId == 3 || msgId == 9 || msgId == 7){
                    devId = message.substring(4, 20);
                    if(dba.IsConOpenOrClose()==false)
                        dba.Open();
                    ConstantClass.CurrentId = devId;
                    dba.prcUpdateOrClean(devId, 1);

                }else if(msgId == 15 || msgId == 13 || msgId == 11 || msgId == 1){
                    if (dba.IsConOpenOrClose()==false)
                        dba.Open();
                    phoneNumber = dba.getSendSmsMobileNo(dba.CurrentWorkingCoordinator(DataBaseAdapter.Key_SendCoord, 1));
                    if(phoneNumber.length()==11){
                        pdNo = phoneNumber.substring(1, 11);
                    }else{
                        pdNo = phoneNumber.substring(0, 10);
                    }
                    devId = "000000" + pdNo;
                    ConstantClass.CurrentId = devId;                
                    dba.prcUpdateOrClean(devId, 1);

                }
                }
                  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                  if(phoneNumber!=null){
                      sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message.toUpperCase(), sentpi, delpi); 
                  }else{
                      throw new java.lang.NullPointerException() ;
                  }               
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dlg = dialog.create();
        dlg.show();       
    }catch(Throwable e){
        dlg = new ExceptionDialog(this.ctx,"Sending SMS",e.getMessage());
        dlg.show();
    }   
}
public BroadcastReceiver sms_send = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
        String Info = "Send Info:";
        switch(getResultCode()){
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Info += "Sms Send Successfull";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            Info += "Sms Sending faild : genric faliure";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            Info += "Sending failed due to no Service";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            Info += "Send failed : Null PDU";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            Info += "Send failed: Radio Service OFF";
            break;
        }
         Toast.makeText(ctx, Info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
public BroadcastReceiver sms_delivered = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        String Info = "SMS Delivered :";
        switch(getResultCode()){
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Info += "Sms Deliverd";
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            Info += "Sms not Delivered";
            break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(ctx, Info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
public IntentFilter getSentIntentFilter(){
    return new IntentFilter(SENT);      
}
public IntentFilter getDeliveredFilter(){
    return new IntentFilter(DELIVERED);
}
/*private void reThrow(MyException ex){
    if(ex.nullPointerException instanceof NullPointerException  ){

    }
}
private class MyException extends Exception{
    public Exception nullPointerException;
    public MyException (){}
    public MyException(Exception NullPointerException){
        this.nullPointerException = NullPointerException;       
    }
}*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dialog.setCancelable(true); should be like  dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

It prevents closure of alert dialog when user presses back button :)

Answer (score 2):

use my class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.mabna.order.R;
import org.mabna.order.dataModel.EntMapMovementsCollection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MessageBox {

    static ArrayList<AlertDialog> arrAlertDialog = new ArrayList<AlertDialog>();
    static OnMyDialogResult mDialogResult; // the callback

    public enum MessageBoxState {
        OK, YesNo
    }

    public enum MessageBoxResult {
        OK, Cancel, Yes, No
    }

    public final static void show(final Activity parent, String title,
            String message, MessageBoxState state) {

        // if (alertDialog != null)
        // {
        // alertDialog.dismiss();
        // }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_messagebox,
                (ViewGroup) parent.findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
        layout.setMinimumWidth(400);

        Typeface tf = Farsi.GetFarsiFont(parent);

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTitle.setText(Farsi.Convert(title));
        tvTitle.setTypeface(tf);
        tvTitle.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

        TextView tvMessage = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        tvMessage.setText(Farsi.Convert(message));
        tvMessage.setTypeface(tf);
        tvMessage.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

        Button btnOK = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        Button btnYes = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
        Button btnNo = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
        Button btnCancel = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnOK.setText(Farsi.Convert("تایید"));
        btnOK.setTypeface(tf);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnOK
                .getLayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        btnOK.setLayoutParams(lp);

        btnYes.setText(Farsi.Convert("بله"));
        btnYes.setTypeface(tf);
        lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnYes
                .getLayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        btnYes.setLayoutParams(lp);

        btnNo.setText(Farsi.Convert("خیر"));
        btnNo.setTypeface(tf);
        btnNo.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnNo
                .getLayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        btnNo.setLayoutParams(lp);

        btnCancel.setText(Farsi.Convert("انصراف"));
        btnCancel.setTypeface(tf);
        btnCancel.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnCancel
                .getLayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        btnCancel.setLayoutParams(lp);

        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                btnOK_onClick();
            }
        });
        btnYes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                btnYes_onClick();
            }
        });
        btnNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                btnNo_onClick();
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                btnCancel_onClick();
            }
        });

        LinearLayout layout_OK = (LinearLayout) layout
                .findViewById(R.id.layout_OK);
        LinearLayout layout_YesNo = (LinearLayout) layout
                .findViewById(R.id.layout_YesNo);

        switch (state) {
        case OK:
            layout_YesNo.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            layout_OK.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case YesNo:
            layout_YesNo.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            layout_OK.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent);
        builder.setView(layout);

        AlertDialog alertDialog;

        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.show();
        mDialogResult = null; // causes each messageBox instance has its own
                                // DialogResult because it removes previous
                                // DialogResults

        arrAlertDialog.add(alertDialog);
        return;
    }

    public static void showException(Activity act,
            Exception e) {
        MessageBox.show(act, "خطا", e.toString(), MessageBoxState.OK);
    }

    public static void showException(Activity act, String additionalDetails,
            Exception e) {
        MessageBox.show(act, "خطا", additionalDetails + ": " + e.toString(),
                MessageBoxState.OK);
    }

    private static AlertDialog getLastDialog() {
        AlertDialog dialog = arrAlertDialog.get(arrAlertDialog.size() - 1);
        arrAlertDialog.remove(dialog);
        return dialog;
    }

    private final static void btnOK_onClick() {
        AlertDialog currentdialog = getLastDialog();
        if (mDialogResult != null) {
            mDialogResult.finish(MessageBoxResult.OK);
            currentdialog.dismiss();
            mDialogResult.dialogClosed();
        } else {
            currentdialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private final static void btnYes_onClick() {
        AlertDialog currentdialog = getLastDialog();
        if (mDialogResult != null) {
            mDialogResult.finish(MessageBoxResult.Yes);
            currentdialog.dismiss();
            mDialogResult.dialogClosed();
        } else {
            currentdialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private final static void btnNo_onClick() {
        AlertDialog currentdialog = getLastDialog();
        if (mDialogResult != null) {
            mDialogResult.finish(MessageBoxResult.No);
            currentdialog.dismiss();
            mDialogResult.dialogClosed();
        } else {
            currentdialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private final static void btnCancel_onClick() {
        AlertDialog currentdialog = getLastDialog();
        if (mDialogResult != null) {
            mDialogResult.finish(MessageBoxResult.Cancel);
            currentdialog.dismiss();
            mDialogResult.dialogClosed();
        } else {
            currentdialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public final static void setDialogResult(OnMyDialogResult dialogResult) {
        mDialogResult = dialogResult;
    }

    public interface OnMyDialogResult {
        void finish(MessageBoxResult result);

        void dialogClosed();
    }

}
```

its layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_YesNo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:text="Button" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNo"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnYes"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:text="Button" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_OK"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOK"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in Activity:

```
MessageBox.show(this, "warning", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxState.YesNo);
MessageBox.setDialogResult(new OnMyDialogResult() {
                    @Override
                    public void finish(MessageBoxResult result) {
                        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                            //...
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void dialogClosed() {
                    }
                });
```